# Print random line into different text file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, printf, shuffle

What I want to do is print a random line from text file A into text file B WITHOUT it choosing the same line twice. So if text file B has a line with the number 25 in it, it will not choose that line from text file A

I have figured out how to print a random line from text file A to text file B, however, I am not sure how to make sure it does not choose the same line twice.

```
echo "$(printf $(cat A.txt | shuf -n 1))" > /home/B.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to print a single line per invocation? Or put all lines from A to B shuffled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -Fxv -f B A | shuf -n 1 >> B
```

First part (`grep`) prints difference of `A` and `B` to stdout, i.e. lines present in `A` but absent in `B`:

- `-F` — Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
- `-x` — Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
- `-v` — Invert the sense of matching.
- `-f FILE` — Obtain patterns from FILE.

Second part (`shuf -n 1`) prints random line from stdin. Output is appended to `B`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry for not being clear on this, but I want it to either replace the file itself or replace the line. I know that's my fault but I honestly had a hard time formulating the question correctly. I did try to remove one of the >, however, when I do that it can still choose the same line twice in a row.

Comment: @user19364455 that's because B is opened *before* grep reads it. With single `>` B is truncated, so for `grep` it's always empty. You can use intermediate file to store last result, e.g. `grep -Fxv -f B A | shuf -n 1 > C; mv C B`

Answer (score 0):

That's not really "random", then. Never mind.

Please try the following `awk` solution - I **think** it does what you're trying to achieve.

```
$ cat A
11758
1368
26149
2666
27666
11155
31832
11274
21743
25
$ cat B
18518
8933
941
32286
1234
25
1608
5284
23040
19028
$ cat pseudo
BEGIN{
  "bash -c 'echo ${RANDOM}'"|getline seed  # Generate a random seed
  srand(seed)                              # use random seed, otherwise each repeated run will generate the same random sequence
  count=0                                  # set a counter 
}
NR==FNR{                                   # while on the first file, remember every number; note this will weed out duplicates!
  b[$1]=1
}
!($1 in b) {                               # for numbers we haven't seen yet (so on the second file, ignoring ones present in file B)
  a[count]=$1                              # remember new numbers in an associative array with an integer index
  count++
}
END{
r=(int(rand() * count))                  # generate a random number in the range of our secondary array's index values
print a[r] >> "B"                        # print that randomly chosen element to the last line of file B
}
$ awk -f pseudo B A
$ cat B
18518
8933
941
32286
1234
25
1608
5284
23040
19028
27666
$
$ awk -f pseudo B A
$ cat B
18518
8933
941
32286
1234
25
1608
5284
23040
19028
27666
31832
```